# operator[][] C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'd like to overload `operator[][]` to give internal access to a 2D array of char in C++.

Right now I'm only overloading `operator[]`, which goes something like

```
class Object
{
    char ** charMap ;
    char* operator[]( int row )
    {
        return charMap[row] ;
    }
} ;
```

It works ok.. Is it possible to override `operator[][]` though?

Comment: There is no operator[][] in C++.

Comment: Overload the array returned by the overload[] OH SHI-

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don’t try to do that – as others have said, overloading `operator []` the way you do actually provides the `[][]` syntax for free. But that’s not a good thing.

On the contrary – it destroys the encapsulation and information hiding of your class by turning an implementation detail – the `char*` pointer – to the outside. In general, this is not advisable.

A better method would be to implement an `operator [,]` which takes more than one argument, or indeed an `operator [][]`. But neither exists in C++.

So the *usual* way of doing this is to ditch `operator []` altogether for more than one dimension. The clean alternative is to use `operator ()` instead because that operator *can* have more than one argument:

```
class Object
{
    char ** charMap ;
    char& operator ()(int row, int column)
    {
        return charMap[row][column];
    }
};
```

For more information, see the article in the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10).

Comment: Your answer raises some good points, but supporting operator[] doesn't need to destroy encapsulation -- instead of returning a pointer, you can return a proxy object that supports operator[] without exposing any internals.

Comment: @Jerry: true but then the proxy object is vastly more work and any benefit is doubtful for a multi-dimensional object (of course, for a *jagged* array, it makes perfect sense).

Comment: The proxy *is* more work, but I think "vastly" overstates it a bit -- the proxy is about a half dozen lines of code (though for N dimensions, you need N-1 proxy classes, so for more than a 3D or so, you generally want to write a template).

Answer (score 17):

There is no operator `[][]`: that's two `[]` operations in a row. You could:

- Have `Object::operator[]` return an object of a second class representing a row, which has its own `operator[]` method that takes a column number;
- Write a `get(int row, int column)` method and use that instead of operator overloading. I'd recommend this unless your object absolutely has to behave like an array.

Comment: +1 If your class is not intended to behave like a function, leave operator() alone.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `operator[][]`. Evaluating `a[x][y]` first calls `operator[]` on `a`, and then `operator[]` again on the result of that.

So the `operator[]` of your object has to return another object with its own `operator[]`, which then will access the requested value.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such thing as `operator[][]`. What you can do is you could return from your `operator[]` method something that has overloaded `operator[]`.

Actually you are doing it now, because you return `char*` which can be indexed using `[]` again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `[][]` operator. What actually happens is that the second `[]` operates on the variable returned by the first `[]`. Because there is already that functionality, it would create ambiguity were there to exist a `[][]` operator.

For example: let's say you have a variable `x` of some type `T`.

```
T x = new T();
```

If we use the `[]` operator, let's say a variable of other type `Q` is returned:

```
Q y = x[0];
```

And then using the `[]` operator on a variable of type `Q` might return a variable of type `R`:

```
R z = y[0];
```

Therefore `x[][]` returns a variable of t ype R.

Let's say we actually were able to overload `[][]` for type T such that it returned a type S:

```
S a = x[0][0];
```

The compiler would have no way of knowing if it should use the `[][]` operator on `x` to return a type `S` variable, or use the `[]` operator twice in a row to return a type `R` variable. This is the ambiguity I mentioned above.

Your best bet *if you're stuck on using square brackets* is to have `operator[]` return a variable which also has `[]` overloaded (or perhaps a variable of the same type, with a flag set), and have that initially returned variable deal with the second `[]`.

But the best solution here  (as mentioned already in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533235/operator-c/2533304#2533304)) is to use a different operator such as `()`.

Comment: The ambiguity could be easily resolved, e.g. by using a greedy parsing. Also, your first code contains an error since `new` returns a *pointer*.